# Find non-repeated files in folder thru powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a folder containing files a.jpg, b.jpg, c.jpg, d.jpg, e.jpg  etc. There is sub-folder within which contains files  b.jpg, c.jpg, d.jpg.

Using powershell I want non-duplicated files i.e. a.jpg, c.jpg and move them to some other location.

thanks

Comment: You mean that you want non-duplicated file names or file contents?

Comment: yes, non duplicated files in a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the Compare-Object cmdlet:

```
$parent = Get-ChildItem D:\temp -Filter *.jpg
$child = Get-ChildItem D:\temp\test -Filter *.jpg
Compare-Object $parent $child -Property Name -PassThru | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination
```

Comment: it is showing this error.
Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'DifferenceObject' because it is null.
At C:\Users\busy\desktop\nondup.ps1:5 char:15
+ Compare-Object <<<<  $parent $child -Property Name -PassThru | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Compare-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CompareObje
   ctCommand

Comment: What's in $child? Is it empty?

Comment: $child contains location of folder where there are copies of files.I have many subfolder which contain copies in main folder,main folder itself contains alot of images.

Comment: it is copying duplicate files, instead of non duplicate.

Comment: What do you get for: Compare-Object $parent $child -Property Name -PassThru ? I get just a.jpg and e.jpg. Isn't this the result you're looking for?